# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does this equation imply that $k=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of $x$.  Denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$ by $D(x) := 2x - \sigma(x)$, and the [sum of the aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$ by $s(x) := \sigma(x) - x$.

Here is my question:

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does this equation imply that $k=1$?
>   $$D(q^k)D(n^2)=2s(q^k)s(n^2)$$

I only know that $k=1$ is true if and only if (one of) the following conditions hold:

**(1)** $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid n^2$

**(2)** $D(n^2) \mid n^2$

**(3)** $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = D(n^2)$

*Source of Equation*

From the fundamental equation
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
we obtain
$$\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^k) - q^k} = \frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
and
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2) - n^2}{\frac{2q^k - \sigma(q^k)}{2}} = \frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)),$$
using the identity
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{C-A}{D-B}.$$

*Reference*

[Conditions Equivalent to the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture on Odd Perfect Numbers](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/)

Comment: @user477343, I think there is a mistake in your second equation.  It should be
$$\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}.$$

Comment: Oh yes, woops. Typo. Sorry about that :) .... Oh, but now that changes everything....

Comment: From the wikipedia page off perfect numbers: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers]. Apparently it still an open problem, but it is proven that k = 1 mod 4

Comment: @user477343, of course following your lead, $k=1$ if and only if $\sigma(q^k)-q^k=\sigma(q^{k-1})=s(q^k)=1$, which is trivial.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't help much, then. Sorry about that :\

Comment: @Dadedidododu, thanks for pointing me to Wikipedia.  I do am aware of the fact that $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @user477343, that is fine.  It is always good to see more and more people getting interested in this kind of maths stuff.  ^_^

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Oh yeah, my comment is useless, apparently you know a lot about this subject, sorry ^^. Did you already try to ask one of your questions on MathOverflow?

Comment: @Dadedidododu, yes I have already asked some of my questions in MathOverflow.  Check them out [here](https://mathoverflow.net/users/10365/jose-arnaldo-bebita-dris?tab=questions).

Comment: In this question, I think you *don't* know that the equation is actually *an identity*, i.e. that it holds for every odd perfect number (of the form $q^kn^2$), so I've undeleted my answer.

Comment: If I'm wrong in the comment above, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: No, @mathlove!  You are very much correct!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is actually an identity since we get

$$\begin{align}D(q^k)D(n^2)&=(2q^k-\sigma(q^k))(2n^2-\sigma(n^2))
\\\\&=(2q^k-\sigma(q^k))\left(2n^2-\frac{2n^2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)}\right)
\\\\&=4n^2q^k-\frac{4n^2q^{2k}}{\sigma(q^k)}-2n^2\sigma(q^k)+2n^2q^k
\\\\&=4n^2q^k-2n^2\sigma(q^k)-\frac{4n^2q^{2k}}{\sigma(q^k)}+2n^2q^k
\\\\&=2\left(\sigma(q^k)-q^k\right)\left(\frac{2n^2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)}-n^2\right)
\\\\&=2\left(\sigma(q^k)-q^k\right)\left(\sigma(n^2)-n^2\right)
\\\\&=2s(q^k)s(n^2)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just some comments that are too long to fit in the space beneath my original question.

For what it is worth, there is the simple relationship
$$D(x) := x - s(x)$$
so that we obtain
$$2s(q^k)s(n^2) = D(q^k)D(n^2) = \bigg(q^k - s(q^k)\bigg)\bigg(n^2 - s(n^2)\bigg)$$ 
$$= q^k n^2 - q^k s(n^2) - n^2 s(q^k) + s(q^k)s(n^2),$$
from which it follows that
$$s(q^k)s(n^2) + q^k s(n^2) + n^2 s(q^k) - q^k n^2 = 0$$
$$s(q^k)s(n^2) + q^k s(n^2) + n^2 s(q^k) + q^k n^2 = 2q^k n^2$$
$$\bigg(s(q^k) + q^k\bigg)s(n^2) + \bigg(s(q^k) + q^k\bigg)n^2 = 2q^k n^2$$
$$\bigg(s(q^k) + q^k\bigg)\bigg(s(n^2) + n^2\bigg) = 2q^k n^2$$
But $s(x) + x = (\sigma(x) - x) + x = \sigma(x)$.  Therefore, we have:
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = 2q^k n^2.$$

However, it is not clear to me whether the preceding argument can or cannot force $k=1$.