# Is $(q^k n^2 \text{ is perfect }) \iff (D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2))$ only true for odd perfect numbers $q^k n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Preamble:  This question is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2698479).)

The title says it all.

> Is $\bigg(q^k n^2 \text{ is perfect }\bigg) \iff \bigg(D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2)\bigg)$ only true for odd perfect numbers $q^k n^2$?

Here,
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$$
is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$,
$$s(x) = \sigma(x) - x$$
is the [sum of the aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$, and $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, the set of positive integers.

**IN RESPONSE TO A CLARIFICATION FROM [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967)**

That is:

> If $\gcd(y,z)=1$, is the biconditional "$yz$ is perfect $\iff D(y)D(z)=2s(y)s(z)$" always true?

Comment: Transferring my answer from **MY ATTEMPT** section (onwards) to an actual answer to this question below, in a bit...

Comment: Thanks for fixing the title, @HenningMakholm.

Comment: I don't get the meaning of the question. Can you make it clearer? Or I would say that it is only true for odd perfect numbers because it *is* about odd perfect numbers.  In the answer below, you say "Therefore, the required relationship $D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2)$ holds for both even and odd perfect numbers." I think this is ambiguous. I don't understand the meaning of the sentence "$D(q^k)D(n^2)=2s(q^k)s(n^2)$ holds for even perfect numbers". You might want to clarify what you want to say.

Comment: @mathlove, for even perfect numbers, just set $q = 2^p - 1$, $k = 1$, and $n^2 = 2^{p-1}$.  Of course, we then have to exclude the even perfect number $6$ because it is squarefree.

Comment: It turns out that the formula still holds even with $6$ included.

Comment: @mathlove, I have edited my question in response to your clarification in your last comment.

Comment: Thanks. One question. Which do you mean (1) Is the biconditional "$yz$ is perfect and $\gcd(y,z)=1$ $\iff$ ..." always true? or (2) Suppose $\gcd(y,z)=1$. Then, is the biconditional "$yz$ is perfect $\iff$ ..." always true?

Comment: @mathlove:  Good catch!  I meant (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $\gcd(y,z)=1$, is the biconditional "$yz$ is perfect $\iff D(y)D(z)=2s(y)s(z)$" always true?

Yes.

If $yz$ is perfect with $\gcd(y,z)=1$, then since
$$\sigma(yz)=\sigma(y)\sigma(z)=2yz$$
we have
$$\begin{align}D(y)D(z)&=(2y-\sigma(y))(2z-\sigma(z))\\\\&=(2y-\sigma(y))\left(2z-\frac{2yz}{\sigma(y)}\right)
\\\\&=4yz-\frac{4y^2z}{\sigma(y)}-2z\sigma(y)+2yz
\\\\&=4yz-2z\sigma(y)-\frac{4y^2z}{\sigma(y)}+2yz
\\\\&=2(\sigma(y)-y)\left(\frac{2yz}{\sigma(y)}-z\right)
\\\\&=2(\sigma(y)-y)(\sigma(z)-z)
\\\\&=2s(y)s(z)\end{align}$$

---

If $D(y)D(z)=2s(y)s(z)$ and $\gcd(y,z)=1$, then
$$\begin{align}&(2y-\sigma(y))(2z-\sigma(z))=2(\sigma(y)-y)(\sigma(z)-z)
\\\\&\implies 4yz-2y\sigma(z)-2z\sigma(y)+\sigma(y)\sigma(z)=2\sigma(y)\sigma(z)-2z\sigma(y)-2y\sigma(z)+2yz
\\\\&\implies 2yz=\sigma(y)\sigma(z)
\\\\&\implies 2yz=\sigma(yz)
\\\\&\implies \text{$yz$ is perfect}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**MY ATTEMPT**

For even perfect numbers $2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$, I get
$$D(2^p - 1)D(2^{p-1}) = (2(2^p - 1) - (2^p))(1) = 2^{p+1} - 2 - 2^p = 2^p - 2$$ 
$$2s(2^p - 1)s(2^{p-1}) = 2(2^p - (2^p - 1))(2^p - 1 - 2^{p-1}) = 2(1)(2^{p-1} - 1) = 2^p - 2.$$

Thus, the equation
$$D(2^p - 1)D(2^{p-1}) = 2s(2^p - 1)s(2^{p-1}) = 2^p - 2$$
is true.

Therefore, the required relationship
$$D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2)$$
holds for both even and odd perfect numbers.

Here is my question:

> Does this proof suffice?

**Added October 02 2018**

Note that it would appear as though we have the corresponding equation
$$D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2) = q^k - 1$$
for odd perfect numbers.  We show here that this assumption is false.

Assuming that $D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2) = q^k - 1$, we get
$$\frac{2(q^k - 1)}{(q - 1)}s(n^2) = q^k - 1,$$
since $s(q^k) = \sigma(q^k) - q^k = \sigma(q^{k-1})$.
This simplifies to
$$s(n^2) = \frac{q-1}{2}$$
or
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} - 1 = \frac{s(n^2)}{n^2} = \frac{q-1}{2n^2}.$$
Using the following results from this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf):
$$\frac{8}{5} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}$$
and
$$\frac{q}{n^2} \leq \frac{q^k}{n^2} < \frac{2}{3},$$
we get a contradiction, as follows:
$$\frac{3}{5} = \frac{8}{5} - 1 < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} - 1 = \frac{s(n^2)}{n^2} = \frac{q-1}{2n^2} < \frac{q}{2n^2} \leq \frac{q^k}{2n^2} < \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}.$$