# What is the common (and simplified) value for $D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2)$ when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939152/28816) to an earlier question, it is shown that
$$D(2^p - 1)D(2^{p-1}) = 2s(2^p - 1)s(2^{p-1}) = 2^p - 2,$$
if $2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$ is an even perfect number, $D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$ is the deficiency of $x$, $s(x) = \sigma(x) - x$ is the sum of the aliquot divisors of $x$, and $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, the set of positive integers.  (Lastly, denote the abundancy index of $x$ by $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$.)

Here is my question in this post:

> What is the common (and simplified) value for $D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2)$ when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

**MOTIVATION**

Since $\gcd(q^k, \sigma(q^k)) = 1$, we have
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} = \frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
$$D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2) = D(q^k)s(q^k)\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$
Then, we have from this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2823496) the following expression for $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)$ in terms of $q$, $k$, $n^2$, and $\sigma(n^2)$:
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{I(q^k)}{s(q^k)}\sigma(n^2) - \frac{1}{I(q^k)s(q^k)}(2n^2).$$

Plugging in this value for $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ into our equation for
$$D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2) = D(q^k)s(q^k)\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)),$$
we obtain
$$D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2) = D(q^k)s(q^k)\Bigg(\frac{I(q^k)}{s(q^k)}\sigma(n^2) - \frac{1}{I(q^k)s(q^k)}(2n^2)\Bigg) = D(q^k)\Bigg(I(q^k)\sigma(n^2) - \frac{1}{I(q^k)}(2n^2)\Bigg).$$

> Note that "if" $I(q^k) = -1$ then the equation would be trivial and the common value would just be $D(q^k)D(n^2)$.  But, of course, we know that
>   $$1 < I(q^k) < \frac{5}{4}.$$

Alas, this is where I get stuck.

Comment: I do realize that the equation $I(q^k)I(n^2) = 2$ gives both
$$I(q^k) = \frac{2}{I(n^2)} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(n^2)}$$
and
$$\frac{2}{I(q^k)} = I(n^2) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}$$
so that
$$I(q^k)\sigma(n^2) - \frac{1}{I(q^k)}(2n^2) = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(n^2)}\cdot{\sigma(n^2)} - \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}\cdot{n^2} = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) = D(n^2),$$
as required.  One of the points of this question is to ponder why, seemingly, $I(q^k) = -1$ appears to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $q$ is prime and using that
$$\sigma(n^2)=\frac{2q^kn^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sigma(q^k)=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$$
we have
$$\begin{align}D(q^k)D(n^2) &= 2s(q^k)s(n^2)
\\\\&=2(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)(\sigma(n^2)-n^2)
\\\\&=2(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)\left(\frac{2q^kn^2}{\sigma(q^k)}-n^2\right)
\\\\&=2n^2\left(3q^k-\sigma(q^k)-\frac{2q^{2k}}{\sigma(q^k)}\right)
\\\\&=2n^2\left(3q^k-\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}-\frac{2q^{2k}(q-1)}{q^{k+1}-1}\right)
\\\\&=2n^2\cdot\frac{3q^k(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)-(q^{k+1}-1)^2-2q^{2k}(q-1)^2}{(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{2n^2(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive (and definitive!) answer, @mathlove!  I will just wait for a couple more days before accepting your answer if there is no other.

Comment: Just a follow-up comment/question to you, @mathlove:  Does this answer imply that $D(n^2) \mid n^2$?

Comment: I do know that 
$$\gcd(D(q^k), s(q^k)) = \gcd\bigg(D(q^k), \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}\bigg) = 1.$$
However, I am unsure if this implies that $D(n^2) \mid n^2$.

Comment: Asking a separate question containing this last inquiry in a bit...