# Does mathlove's answer imply that $D(n^2) \mid n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In what follows, set $\sigma(x)$ to be the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, and let
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$$
be the deficiency of $x$, and let
$$s(x) = \sigma(x) - x$$
be the sum of the aliquot divisors of $x$.

An earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2939248) asks:

> What is the common (and simplified) value for $D(q^k)D(n^2) = 2s(q^k)s(n^2)$ when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

In the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948403/28816), MSE user [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967) writes:

> $$\begin{align}D(q^k)D(n^2) &= 2s(q^k)s(n^2)
> \\\\&=\frac{2n^2(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)}\end{align}.$$

Now, I know that 
$$s(q^k) = \sigma(q^k) - q^k = \sigma(q^{k-1}) = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}$$
and that
$$\gcd(D(q^k), s(q^k)) = 1.$$

Here is my question in this post:

> Does [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967)'s answer imply that $D(n^2) \mid n^2$?

I ask because the divisibility condition $D(n^2) \mid n^2$ for the non-Euler part $n^2$ is [known to be equivalent](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/) to the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture (that is, $k=1$) for odd perfect numbers.